# Is it possible to reload dynamic libraries while a golang program running?

Tags: go, dynamic, dll

**Edit:** (from comments) I'm looking for a way to modify parts of my program while it's running. I wrote this code only as an example.
Assuming we have such a code:

```
for {
    t := time.Now()
    fmt.Print(t.Minute(), ":", t.Second(), " ")
    testdll.Testf()
    time.Sleep(time.Second * 2)
}
```

and

```
package testdll
import (
    "fmt"
)
//Testf 
func Testf() {
    fmt.Println("hello I'm version 1")
}
```

Is it possible to get this result during runtime when testdll is updated to version 2 and rebuilt?

```
14:29 hello I'm version 1
14:31 hello I'm version 1
14:33 hello I'm version 1
14:35 hello I'm version 2
14:37 hello I'm version 2
14:39 hello I'm version 2
```

Comment: You will have to explain why you think such behavior might be possible. Just because you name a package "xyzDLL" does not mean it is loaded or linkes at runtime.

Comment: I'm looking for a way to modify part of my program while it's running.
I wrote this code only as an example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Is it possible to reload dynamic libraries while a golang program running?

Yes. See https://golang.org/pkg/plugin/

> Is it possible to get this result during runtime when testdll is updated to version 2 and rebuilt?

No.

Comment: It looks like the plugin can load the library while the program is running but can't reload and can't even close it.

Comment: @SayyedMojtabaRazawian Yes. This is the reason for the No.